# Near(ish) 90's era sci-fi novel featuring conflict between east and west-bloc powers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this in the early 1990's but I couldn't say when the novel was actually written. The setting and plot points that are I remember are that it was set in the nearish future and the main factions are essentially successor states to the Eastern-bloc (essentially Russia, not sure if China featured) and Western-bloc. Nation states in the Western-bloc still exist to some extent. It could almost be described as alternate history if it wasn't set in the future (the author clearly expected the political dynamics of the 60's - 80's to continue).

I'm not sure if the book would count as dystopian or post-apocalyptic as, although there may have been limited nuclear exchanges in the setting, governments and society where still functioning albeit at a very high level of security.

The characters that I recall were the male and female protagonist - he was a serving member of the western allies armed forces, she I'm don't really recall. During the course of the story they also come into contact with an Asian female (I seem to remember Japanese but could be Chinese) who was an agent either of the armed forces or security service of her faction, which was either western-allied or neutral but west sympathetic. The male protagonist is favorably disposed to her at first as he assumed she was an innocent non-combatant only to be disappointed when, in the wake of some kind of bombing (at a space port?) it was revealed that she had martial arts training and sub-dermal implants in the edges of her hand to enhance the lethality of chop attacks.

Cyberpunk wasn't a huge theme of the book but those kind of body modifications did feature in the story, primarily as weapons for sleeper agents.

The antagonists were more caricatures then characters, being pretty stereotypical bad-Russian types.

I don't remember a lot of scenes or even the overall plot of the story, beyond the eastern-bloc being up to no good and the protagonists trying to prevent the the cold war from going hot. The two scenes I do remember is one early in that some of air attacks causes a sodium salts-cooled nuclear reactor to melt-down and explode and the bombing in the air or space port.